# Is there a way to load thumbnails of images without loading full image and resizing?

Tags: iphone

I have an app where I take multiple photos using the Camera and need to display the taken photos as thumbnails after taking.

Is it possible to load a thumbnail of a large photo without having to load the full image?

Currently i'm thinking of saving 2 versions of a photo when its taken with the camera, but just wondered if there is a way to load a thumbnail of an image from a file to save me having to have 2 versions of the file..

Thanks

Comment: Are you using ALAssets and saving to the camera roll? If so, ALAsset has a thumbnail property (iOS 4 and up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't do this automagically, as you said you have two options :

- Open full-size and generate thumbnail (that you could keep in a cache)
- Open a Pre-saved thumbnail (that you could get from a cache)

Depending on what you want to do, there are several ways and open source projects to do this.

Comment: ok, I suspected that.  I'll just have to save a thumbnail of the image and load that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](http://www.nickkuh.com/iphone/how-to-create-square-thumbnails-using-iphone-sdk-cg-quartz-2d/2010/03/). It might help you to start with.